# I have tried multiple times but getting column ambiguous error

Tags: oracle10g

```
SELECT 
    V_CUSTSAL.DSTBID, V_CUSTSAL.DSTB, V_CUSTSAL.BATCH, 
    V_CUSTSAL.RATE, V_CUSTSAL.NRV, V_CUSTSAL.ACTUAL, 
    V_CUSTSAL.VACTUAL, V_CUSTSAL.BONUS, V_CUSTSAL.TEAMNAME,   
    V_CUSTSAL.GRP, V_CUSTSAL.PRD, V_CUSTSAL.VACTUALXDP, 
    V_CUSTSAL.NETVALUE, V_CUSTSAL.NETVALUEXDP, V_CUSTSAL.YEAR, V_CUSTSAL.YEARMONTH, 
    V_DAILYSTOCK.MONTH, V_DAILYSTOCK.DSTB, 
    V_DAILYSTOCK.NRV, V_DAILYSTOCK.PRD, V_DAILYSTOCK.STOCK, 
    V_DAILYSTOCK.VALUE, V_DAILYSTOCK.YEAR
FROM 
    SAS.V_CUSTSAL 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    SAS.V_DAILYSTOCK ON (SAS.V_CUSTSAL.DSTBID = SAS.V_DAILYSTOCK.DSTBID);
```

Comment: There are 2 tables (V_CUSTSAL & V_DAILYSTOCK) from which i want to get data.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be qualifying all your column names, so you shouldn't be getting this error.

Perhaps using table aliases will help solve the problem:

```
SELECT c.DSTBID, c.DSTB, c.BATCH, c.RATE, c.NRV, c.ACTUAL,
       c.VACTUAL, c.BONUS, c.TEAMNAME, c.GRP, c.PRD, c.VACTUALXDP,
       c.NETVALUE, c.NETVALUEXDP, c.YEAR, c.YEARMONTH,
       d.MONTH, d.DSTB, d.NRV, d.PRD, d.STOCK, d.VALUE, d.YEAR
FROM SAS.V_CUSTSAL c FULL OUTER JOIN
     SAS.V_DAILYSTOCK d
     ON c.DSTBID = d.DSTBID;
```

See.  I think I see the problem.  `NRV` and `YEAR` appear twice.  Let's just give the second another alias:

```
SELECT c.DSTBID, c.DSTB, c.BATCH, c.RATE, c.NRV, c.ACTUAL,
       c.VACTUAL, c.BONUS, c.TEAMNAME, c.GRP, c.PRD, c.VACTUALXDP,
       c.NETVALUE, c.NETVALUEXDP, c.YEAR, c.YEARMONTH,
       d.MONTH, d.DSTB, d.NRV as ds_NRV, d.PRD, d.STOCK, s.VALUE,
       d.YEAR as ds.YEAR
```